# using a function no more then 1 time in 2 sec in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function that starts on mouse wheel scroll but, if i do a longer scroll, it executes for 2-3 times. So i have to find a way to prevent it running if it is called more then 1 time in 2 sec let's say. Any ideas?

PS : this is my function. if you know a better way to start it on scroll and not taking in consideration how long it's the scroll, i would appreciate it as well.

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
// Firefox
window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
}
// IE 6/7/8

var s = 0;
function MouseWheelHandler(e) {

// cross-browser wheel delta
var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));     
e.preventDefault();
                ...
 }
```

UPDATE: I worked out my own version of the code, based on the ideas that i've read in the comments and answers. This is it :

```
function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
var e = window.event || e;   

// cross-browser wheel delta
 // old IE support
var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));     
 e.preventDefault();
GoUpDown(delta,e);

}
function GoUpDown(delta,e) {
                        if(timer ==0){ timer =1;
                            setTimeout(function () {timer =0;},4200);
  /*function stuff*/
}
```

Comment: Fix the tags and title. JavaScript is *not* related to Java.

Comment: Use time (milliseconds) So the code is only executed once every X seconds?  Could that be an option?

Comment: @Nicolas OP tells a good joke; question is not about Java..

Comment: i have to use php as well to get that time, or there is a javascript function to return it?

Comment: What you are looking for is called "throttle": [`[javascript] throttle`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+throttle)

Comment: i think that throttle is the solution, still, i have to learn how to use it, because right now it doesn't work ;)) i'll get some documentation about it, and if i still can't solve my problem, i'll let you know

Comment: you can use underscore `throttle` method if you already have the library btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A throttle way modified from Morten OC's debounce code

http://jsfiddle.net/43sgpme7/13/

```
var interval = 2000;
var count = 0;

function action() {
    count++;
    $("p").html(new Date().getTime() + "-" + count)
}

$(".scroll").scroll(function () {
    var self = this;
    if (this.lastScroll === undefined) {
        this.lastScroll = Date.now() - interval;
    }

    /*calculate how long until next execution should happen*/
    var nextTime = interval - Date.now() + this.lastScroll;
    /*it doesn't make sense that time range is smaller than 0*/
    if (nextTime < 0) {
        nextTime = 0;
    }

    if (this.scrollTo) clearTimeout(this.scrollTo);
    this.scrollTo = setTimeout(function () {
        self.lastScroll = Date.now();
        action();
    }, nextTime);
});
```

Comment: i tried your code as well, it works, but i prefer Preston S one :0 thx anyway :)

Comment: I just want to point out the difference between this answer and my own.  This one executes the method even after scrolling has stopped  (more of an interval debounce) where mine is a true throttle implementation.  Also, you stole my checkmark :P

Comment: It makes sure the last scroll also fire the function, so if you use it to update layout position ...etc. you will not miss some action and result in strange layout. which means all action should be handled instead of just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple throttle function. It returns a new function that will only allow the passed in function to run at the specified `interval` (in milliseconds).

```
function throttleFunction(func, interval){
    return function(){
        if(!func.lastRunTime || func.lastRunTime < Date.now() - interval){
            func.lastRunTime = Date.now();

            func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

Add it into your code like this:

```
//Only run every 2000 milliseconds
var throttledMouseWheelHandler = throttleFunction(MouseWheelHandler, 2000);
// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", throttledMouseWheelHandler , false);
// Firefox
window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", throttledMouseWheelHandler , false);
```

```js
function throttleFunction(func, interval) {
  return function() {
    if (!func.lastRunTime || func.lastRunTime < Date.now() - interval) {
      func.lastRunTime = Date.now();

      func.apply(arguments);
    }
  }
}

document.body.onclick = throttleFunction(function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'clicked';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div>Click ME (only registers every 2 seconds)</div>
```

Comment: @user3054345 I updated my answer with one small but important detail.  Passing `this` to the apply call as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of easy, I included jQuery in this example.. You could rewrite it to native..

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/43sgpme7/

```
$(".scroll").scroll(function ()
{
    if (this.scrollTo) clearTimeout(this.scrollTo);
    this.scrollTo = setTimeout(function ()
    {
        $("p").html(new Date().getTime())

    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This is called "debounce". The function won't be called until 1 second after the last scroll event. It seems like the OP is looking for throttle instead, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hmm yeah maybe he is asking for throttle instead.. I misunderstood.. lets see if he can use it.